# optional permissions alert going to some other opened tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and recently I implemented a button in the browser action Popup for asking browser optional permissions from the user.

but I noticed recently that whenever the user has 5-10 chrome tabs opened and the user clicks on the enable button from the browser action Popup, the optional permissions alert appears in some other opened chrome window, rather than the one from which the enable button was clicked.

this is the optional permissions function that runs whenever I click on the enable button in the browser action dropdown

```
chrome.permissions.request({
            origins: ["<all_urls>"]
          }, function(granted){
            console.log('Call successful.');
            if (granted) {
              localStorage.setItem('permissions', 'granted');
}})
```

we also have same enable button on the extension onboarding page and any currently opened tab DOM, this behavior only takes place whenever the enable button is clicked from the browser action Popup, it works fine if I click the enable button from a currently opened tab or the onboarding page of the extension

I have researched a lot around this issue, but I wasn't able to find a fix for it

I even tried to call the same above listed function, in background.js file by using message passing from the original browser action Popup js file, but the behavior didn't changed

Comment: By "dropdown", do you mean "popup"? As in [Documentation > Extensions > Develop extensions and themes > Design the user interface > Popup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/#popup).

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). AFAIK, you're not supposed to post screenshots of code on SO.

Comment: @ThomasMueller yea I mean "popup" only

Comment: @ThomasMueller yea I added it by mistake, and updated it immediately, must be some internet problem on my end, it took some time to update

Comment: It's a bug https://crbug.com/1101407. You can use web_accessible_resources to add an iframe to the web page and ask for permissions inside or open a new small window from the popup and ask there.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see, thanks for sending this on, really helpful !